# Sending XRP tokens from a smart contract to a wallet

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, web3.php

I'm trying to use a PHP library (Web3.php) to achieve a transaction of XRP tokens from a simple smart contract to a wallet.

```
use Web3\Web3;
use Web3\Providers\HttpProvider;
use Web3\RequestManagers\HttpRequestManager;
use Web3\Contract;
use Web3\Utils;
use Web3p\EthereumTx\Transaction;

// PARAMETERS
$prov = 'https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/42...0a/bsc/testnet';
//$prov = 'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/';
$web3 = new Web3(new HttpProvider(new HttpRequestManager($prov)));
$tokenAddress = "0xa83575490d7df4e2f47b7d38ef351a2722ca45b9"; // XRP token
$senderAccount = "0xF2935F3.....522Ea32342496eF694"; // Marketing Pool
$senderOwner = "0x5f1c07282.....2Eb86E6DEE3"; // Account 5 (Owner)
$destAccount = "0xA995b19209.....32eE044B";
$senderPK = "4193617b3a8b...00102629b75ee";
$abi = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/resources/ERC20AbiMarketingPool.json');
$contract = new Contract($prov, $abi);
$eth = $contract->eth;
$secondsToWaitForReceipt = 60;
$factorToMultiplyGasEstimate = 600;
$chainId = 97; // Testnet
$amount = 0.11;
$amountInWholeNumber = intval($amount) * (10 ** 18);

// TRANSFER XRP TO WALLET
$rawTransactionData = '0x' . $contract->at($tokenAddress)->getData('transfer', $destAccount, $amountInWholeNumber);
$transactionCount = null;
$eth->getTransactionCount($senderOwner, function ($err, $transactionCountResult) use(&$transactionCount) {
    if($err) { 
        echo 'getTransactionCount error: ' . $err->getMessage() . "<br>"; 
    } else {
        $transactionCount = $transactionCountResult;
    }
});
echo "\$transactionCount=$transactionCount" . "<br>";

$transactionParams = [
    'nonce' => "0x" . dechex($transactionCount->toString()),
    'from' => $senderAccount,
    'to' =>  $destAccount,
    'gasPrice' =>  hexdec(dechex(20000000000)),
    'value' => '0x0',
    'data' => $rawTransactionData
];

$estimatedGas = null;
$eth->estimateGas($transactionParams, function ($err, $gas) use (&$estimatedGas) {
    if ($err) {
        echo 'estimateGas error: ' . $err->getMessage() . "<br>"; 
    } else {
        $estimatedGas = $gas;
    }
});
echo "\$estimatedGas=$estimatedGas" . "<br>";

$gasPriceMultiplied = hexdec(dechex($estimatedGas->toString())) * $factorToMultiplyGasEstimate;
echo "\$gasPriceMultiplied=$gasPriceMultiplied" . "<br>";
$transactionParams['gas'] = '0x' . dechex($gasPriceMultiplied);
$transactionParams['chainId'] = $chainId;
$tx = new Transaction($transactionParams);
$signedTx = '0x' . $tx->sign($senderPK);

$txHash = null;
$eth->sendRawTransaction($signedTx, function ($err, $txResult) use (&$txHash) {
    if($err) { 
        echo 'transaction error: ' . $err->getMessage() . "<br>"; 
    } else {
        $txHash = $txResult;
    }
});
echo "\$txHash=$txHash" . "<br>";
```

The transaction takes place but it says: $senderOwner sent 0 BNB to $destAccount?
I could call a withdraw function the smart contract but would it be safe?

**EDIT 1**

So I changed a few things:

```
$amountInWholeNumber = 900000000000000;

$rawTransactionData = '0x' . $contract->getData('transfer', $destinationAddress, $amountInWholeNumber);

$transactionParams = [
    'nonce' => "0x" . dechex($transactionCount->toString()),
    'from' => $fromContract,
    'to' =>  $contractAddress,
    'gasPrice' => '0x' . dechex(10000000000),
    'value' => '0x0',
    'data' => $rawTransactionData
];
```

Although I specified 'from' as the smart contract holding XRP ($fromContract), it sends the amount from the owner of the contract instead ($senderOwner)... Is it because I sign the transaction using the owner's PK?

**EDIT 2**

I tried to call this transfer function from solidty:

```
function withdrawToken(address _tokenContract, uint256 _amount, address _recipient, address _sender) public payable {
    IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(_tokenContract);
    require(_sender == _owner, "Only owner can withdraw");
    require(IERC20(_tokenContract).balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Insufficient Funds");
    tokenContract.transfer(_recipient, _amount);
}
```

Using this:

```
$contract->at($senderAccount)->send('withdrawToken', [
    '_tokenContract' => $tokenAddress,
    '_amount' => $amountInWholeNumber,
    '_recipient' => $destAccount,
    '_sender' => $senderOwner
], function ($err, $transres) use(&$done) {
    if($err) { 
        echo 'error: ' . $err->getMessage() . "<br>"; 
    } else {
        $done = $transres;
    }
});
```

and got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please make sure you have put all function params and callback. 
in /home/project3/vendor/sc0vu/web3.php/src/Contract.php:561 Stack trace: #0 
/home/project3/public_html/app/withdraw_function.php(58): Web3\Contract->send('withdrawToken', Array, 
Object(Closure)) #1 {main} thrown in /home/project3/vendor/sc0vu/web3.php/src/Contract.php on line 561
```

Comment: Do you have failing transaction hash?

Comment: @Ismael Please see the EDIT I just posted. The transactions are taking place but the funds are sent from the owner's account instead of the smart contract. Here is a receipt: 0xe23311d9e65a7a33a583d431fb8b298549e8dd0f02452c25025a8952376c115c

Comment: The 'from' is derived from the transaction signature. I see nothing wrong with the transaction the value transferred is 0.0009 * 10**18 from the sender.

Comment: @Ismael So how do you make the fund come from thecontract itself instead of the owner's?

Comment: The easiest is to make the contract do the transfer by itself. Add a function foo and inside the function the contract does `token.transfer(recipient, amount);`.

Comment: function withdrawToken(address _tokenContract, uint256 _amount, address _recipient) public onlyOwner {
        IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(_tokenContract);
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Not enough money");
        tokenContract.approve(_recipient, _amount);
        tokenContract.transfer(_recipient, _amount);
    }

Comment: The problem is that we3,php doesn't call that function properly. Something wrong. I get this: Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please make sure you have put all function params and callback. 
in /home/project3/vendor/sc0vu/web3.php/src/Contract.php:561 Stack trace: #0 
/home/project3/public_html/app/withdraw_function.php(58): Web3\Contract->send('withdrawToken', Array, 
Object(Closure)) #1 {main} thrown in /home/project3/vendor/sc0vu/web3.php/src/Contract.php on line 561

Comment: There's no need to call `approve` in `withdrawToken`. How do you call withdrawToken from php? You can edit your own question if you need to add extra code.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a php developer but I believe the correct syntax is

```$contract->at($senderAccount)->send('withdrawToken', $tokenAddress, $amountInWholeNumber, $destAccount, $senderOwner, function ($err, $transres) use(&$done) {```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132820/discussion-between-ismael-and-vincent).

Comment: @Vincent Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Isaiassilvaamaya No sir, I did not.